# Is there a bug in Gnuplot 5.2 (patch 5) with `multiplot` command?

Tags: gnuplot

I'm running Gnuplot version 5.2, patch level 5, and I am getting unexpected behavior from the `multiplot` command. In efforts to produce two plots, one smaller and superimposed on the larger one, I am using the `multiplot` environment in the following way:

```
reset
set multiplot
set origin 0,0
set size 1,1
plot "first_file.dat"
set origin 5,5
set size 0.5,0.5
plot "second_file.dat"
unset multiplot
```

When I first run `set multiplot` an empty canvas shows up that I close. Then, when I enter `unset multiplot` nothing happens. From following instructions online it seems like the `unset` command is supposed to produce the plot, but it doesn't. Am I doing something wrong, or is there a potential bug with this version?

Comment: You probably meant "set origin 0.5, 0.5".

Comment: I want the origin of the second plot to be at (5,5). But even with your suggestion, the behavior of `set multiplot` and `unset multiplot` is not as expected. `set multiplot` creates and shows an empty canvas on `X11`, while `unset multiplot` does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you close the empty canvas? You won't see anything until you plot your data. The following code gives two superimposed plots. However, the `set origin` coordinates are relative to the screen (ranging from 0.0,0.0 to 1.0,1.0). If you want to place the second graph relative to some coordinates of the first graph, this probably would require some calculations.

```
reset session
set colorsequence classic

set multiplot         # will show an emtpy canvas
plot sin(x) lt 1      # will show the first plot

set origin 0.1, 0.45  # origin coordinates are relative to the screen 
                      # not to the coordinates of the first plot
set size 0.5,0.5
plot cos(x) lt 2      # will show the second plot on top of the first plot

unset multiplot
```

Result (wxt terminal):

[image]

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you for the info about how `set origin` works. I was used to placing things with respect to plot, which is not the case here!